# Using temporary tables in SQL to generate and fill a "data template"

Tags: sql

So let's say I have a table, call it 'orders' that looks like this:

```
customer|order_type|price
-------- ---------- -----
"Bob"   |"Delivery"|100
"Nancy" |"Delivery"|200
```

Where customer can be any name, and order_type can be either 'Delivery' or 'Pickup'

If I have a (temporary) helper table that just contains the order_type field with two rows, one for each order type, I can write a query like this and get close to what I want

```
SELECT 
    customer, temp.order_type 
FROM 
    (SELECT order_type FROM helper) temp 
LEFT JOIN
    orders ON temp.order_type = orders.order_type AND name = 'Bob'
```

This will give me the following:

```
customer|order_type|price
-------- ---------- -----
 NULL   |"Pickup"  |NULL
"Bob"   |"Delivery"|100
"Nancy" |"Delivery"|200
```

What can I do to make my output look like this:

```
customer|order_type|price
-------- ---------- -----
"Bob"   |"Pickup"  |NULL
"Bob"   |"Delivery"|100
"Nancy" |"Pickup"  |NULL
"Nancy" |"Delivery"|200
```

FWIW, this is a highly simplified example of my ultimate goal, and for this ultimate goal assume I cannot just create separate records where 'price' is NULL

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle

Comment: A proprietary one developed by my company and used internally only, if you have more specific questions I can try to answer them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't guarantee this will work since you're using a proprietary database, but this is an ANSI way of doing it:

```
SELECT
    name,order_type,price
FROM
    orders
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    name,helper.order_type,null
FROM
    orders
    CROSS JOIN helper 
WHERE
    (name,helper.order_type) 
     NOT IN (SELECT name,order_type
              FROM orders)
ORDER BY
  1,2
```

A simpler, but more fragile solution would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  name,
  helper.order_type,
  sum(CASE WHEN orders.order_type=helper.order_type 
           THEN price 
           ELSE null end) price
FROM
    orders
    CROSS JOIN helper 
GROUP BY
  name,helper.order_type
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcb7d/8) -   I added some additional values to illustrate the effect.

Comment: Your second solution seems to be working slightly better for me, but it seems that the group by is sometimes reporting, say, Bob's delivery price as NULL, even though it should have a value (and I say this not from running your solution against my example, but against my actual database). Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I'll try, but I'm thinking it might be best to consult with in-house experts at this point. Thanks for your help so far and I will edit the question if I can get some good sample data.

Comment: Ok.  If you, please add a comment here too, else I won't know you've updated the question.

Comment: Here's an sql fiddle with a better example, sorry I changed everything around but I think the example makes more sense now: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0bbd/1
And you can see that "Jane" should have a D in Math, but instead the query reports null. Do you think I should edit the whole question, or just keep the discussion to these comments?

Comment: I tried again to use your first query, but it doesn't work when I need to select a small set of customer/students from my table (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d58c2a/2, Jane-English-null doesn't appear because Timmy has a grade in English). Unless you have any more ideas, I'll consult with company experts and see if there are other ways to achieve what I'm trying to do

Comment: I finally got your first query to work (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d58c2a/3), but it seems our proprietary system doesn't like queries of the type "(column1, column2) NOT IN (select column1, column2 from table)". Thanks again for all your help, I certainly feel like I have a stronger grasp on cross joins now :)

Comment: Finally got it to work, by replacing the "," with "||", which seems to be our way of concatenating strings. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work in SQL server, not even with the concat command. Oh well, I guess that one is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: The first method might work better for you.  See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d58c2a/13.  I changed the `sum` to `max` since the values are character now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get that result using two subqueries. [You can check it out in this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aea2e/13). It's set up for SQL Server 2012, but I think you can probably get it to work with your internal system.

```
SELECT s1.Customer, s1.Order_Type, s2.Price
FROM (
  SELECT o.Customer, t.Order_Type
  FROM dbo.Orders o
  CROSS JOIN dbo.Helper t
) s1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Customer, Order_Type, Price
  FROM dbo.Orders
) s2 ON s1.Customer = s2.Customer AND s1.Order_Type = s2.Order_Type
ORDER BY Customer, Order_Type, Price
```